# Get all _POST vars using a loop in Yii

Tags: post, yii, get, request

I have code

```
$str = '';
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $str .= $k.'='.$v;
}
```

Is it possible to make same with **CHttpRequest**? Didn't find any [method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#methods) for it.

Need to **md5** it in the end, so there is no security issues.

Comment: It looks like the methods represent the variables you're talking about...

Comment: Problem is to insert that method into loop.

Comment: I don't think that CHttpRequest has a method to get all the POST values. You can only get one by specifying its name.
Why don't you want to use the $_POST var?

Comment: @darkheir Now I'm using $_POST, but always better to use framework default methods instead of direct usage. It's same if I for every select from DB make direct MySQL query.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you it's cleaner to use the Framework methods!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think CHttpRequest is intended to get the post data, Yii itself uses the $_POST variable, Gii's default output for example can be this:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Model;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Model'])) //<- POST data var
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Model']; //<- POST data var
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, you're right. So answer for this question is `Using $_POST is ok.` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend **CHttpRequest** component and rewrite public method **getPost()**

```
class HttpRequest extends CHttpRequest {
    public function getPost($name = null, $defaultValue = null) {
        $data = ($this->_isJsonEncoded()) ? \CJSON::decode($this-
            >getRawBody()) : $_POST;

        if (isset($data[$name])) {
            return $data[$name];
        } elseif (isset($defaultValue)) {
            return $defaultValue;
        } else {
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to include the new component class in **config/main.php** file:

```
'request' => [
     'class' => 'application.components.HttpRequest',
 ],
```

Now, you can get all **$_POST** data in this way:

```
Yii::app()->request->getPost();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get array using getRestParams().

```
Yii::app()->request->getRestParams()
```

OR

```
 Yii::$app->request->getRestParams()
```

**Reference:** [CHttpRequest - getRestParams](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getRestParams-detail)